# Java how to test aspect Method

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, aspect

I would like to write tests for my aspects, but I have no idea how to do this or even how to start. I have my service method that saves some object and my point cut aspect that saves information about this operation to my database. I would like to write a test to just see whether my aspect is being executed after calling the service method, but I don't know how I should inject my dependencies or mock them.

My service method:

```
private final BookRepository bookRepository;

public Book saveBook(final Book book){
    return bookRepository.save(book);
}
```

My aspect:

```
private final BooksAudRepository booksAudRepository;
private final BookRepository bookRepository;

@After("execution(* com.library.service.BookService.saveBook(..))" +
        "&& args(book)")
public void saveBookLogDb(Book book) {
    log.info("BookAud INSERT operation is being caught");
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    ReaderDetails readerDetails = (ReaderDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
    BooksAud booksAud = buildSaveBookAud(book, readerDetails.getUsername());
    booksAudRepository.save(booksAud);
    log.info("BookAud INSERT operation is being recorded");
}
```

And here I have my test method that is a mix of my attempts to write that test, so there is nothing useful. Can anyone point me out how to start this? How do I call the dependencies?

Comment: Do you want a unit or integration test? Of course, you should have both. But which one here? My answer depends on yours. In general, a unit test should test the aspect in isolation and not verify if it is triggered when calling the target method. The latter would be an integration test. But in both cases, make sure to test the actual aspect and not the aspect framework as such.

Comment: Please also note that it would be helpful to post full classes with package names, imports, constructors, annotations etc., so e.g. I can see how the private final fields in the aspect are initialised. The best would be an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), either here in your question or on GitHub. You also forgot to mention which mocking framework (if any) and which test framework (JUnit 4/5, Spock, TestNG or whatever) you are using. So omitting your failing test method is achieving the opposite of what you want: Nobody can help you other than with general hints.

Comment: Please be kind enough to provide some feedback to the people who are trying to help you. Saying nothing is simply not very polite.